# Using gdal2xyz.py to get Raster's pixel center coordinate with it's value

Tags: gdal, raster-to-point

I am using gdal2xyz to get pixel values translated to a point layer. my values have decimals and when I use gdal2xyz the decimals are removed. so value that were 0.345 become 345 and values that were 1.234 become 1234. I am using it like this:

```
os.system('gdal2xyz.py -csv ' + Folder_2 + '/Water_Vapor.tif ' + Output+ '/merged.csv')
```

Comment: Check with `gdalinfo Water_Vapor.tif` what is the datatype and if the values are stored as scaled. Add the output to the question if you can't interpret it.

Comment: Thanksfor helping me out on this. here is a link to a txt file from that output:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aCSc5AaIijMpkdtYQE38wCB3IyaB2Xr_/view?usp=sharing